# Input with autocomplete capability - Asyncronic search

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am learning to program and I want to do an asynchronous search. I got a code that works, but I do not understand why, I would like to know if anyone can help me to understand the code guide.

```js
const list = document.getElementById("results");

const autoResults = (query) => {
  fetch(`https://wagon-dictionary.herokuapp.com/autocomplete/${query}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      data.words.forEach((result) => {
        const resultLi = `<li>${result}</li>`;
        list.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", resultLi);
      });
    });
};

const form = document.querySelector("#container input");

form.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
  const inputText = event.currentTarget.value;
  autoResults(inputText);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search">
  <ul id="results" class="list-inline">

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a working snippet. I had to remove a `}` from `${query}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an improved version with comments

I use a *debouncing* method to not hammer the dictionary with a few letters

```js
const list = document.getElementById("results");

const autoResults = (query) => {
  fetch(`https://wagon-dictionary.herokuapp.com/autocomplete/${query}`) // call the site
    .then(response => response.json())   // we get a JSON string back, parse it
    .then((data) => {                    // here is a data object  
      list.innerHTML = data.words        // here is an array of words
        .map(word => `<li>${word}</li>`) // create a list using map 
        .join('');                       // join to make a long string
    });
};
const inputField = document.querySelector("#container input"); // it is a field, not a form
let tId, inputText; // make two global variables for timeout and text
inputField.addEventListener("input", (event) => { // input handles a paste too
  const inputText = event.target.value;
  // debounce
  clearTimeout(tId); // stop any ongoing timeout 
  tId = setTimeout(() => autoResults(inputText), 300); // give the user 300 ms to type a letter
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search">
  <ul id="results" class="list-inline">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for it! I have it clear

Comment: Please note JSON is a STRING representation of a POJO (Plain Old JavaScript Object) and the statement `response => response.json()` converts the [String to Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json)